# Ifelse statement inside apply function is not returning any value

Tags: r, apply

I have been trying to do some manipulation on default Diamond dataset and came up with a problem where I need to consider two column values cut=ideal and clarity=vs2. If these two are true then my function will return total count of these types of diamonds from the first n number of samples.
my code is the following:

```
idealvs2<- function(n){
  k<-0
  s<-apply(head(diamonds,n),1, function(x)ifelse(diamonds$cut=="Ideal" &&  diamonds$clarity=="VS2",k<-k+1,k<-k+0))
  return(k)
}
```

`idealvs2(10)` is supposed to answer 3 which isn't happening.

please help

Comment: Could you show the expected output for the first 6 rows so that others understand what u wanted.  The `&&` should be `&`.  When you do an `apply`, it converts to a `matrix`, assuming that there are factor columns, it could create problem

Comment: The expected output for the first 6 rows would be 1. corrected & , thnks

Comment: For 6 rows, should it be 2?

Comment: Do NOT use assignments in the second and third arguments to `ifelse`.

Comment: sorry, if we say cut="verygood" and clarity ="SI1" then the function should return 4 for first 25 rows.

Answer (score 0):

What we need is a simple function to `sum` the logical vector (`cut == "Ideal" | clarity == "VS2"`)

```
f1 <- function(dat, n){
        tmp <- head(dat, n)
        with(tmp, sum(cut== "Ideal" | clarity == 'VS2'))
 }

f1(diamonds, 10)
#[1] 3
```